# TCL regex issue - Finding a router parent interface

Tags: regex, networking, tcl, expect

I'm doing some Expect / TCL scripting to grab important information from routers.

One of my objectives is to grab the name of the WAN interface of a router using the IP I logged into the router as a reference.

Example Router IP: 66.66.66.66 - This is contained within variable $rtrname.

Using expect, I evaluate the below data ($expect_out(buffer)) with the following expression, and output it to the value $wan...

Expression:

```
regexp (.*?)(?=(?:\..*?)?\s{2,}$rtrname) $expect_out(buffer) wan
```

$expect_out(buffer):

```
Router1#sh ip int brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.10      55.55.55.55  YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.20      66.66.66.66  YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         77.77.77.77   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         192.168.1.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

With $rtrname == 66.66.66.66 this returns $wan as GigabitEthernet0/0 correctly, which is what I want.

Unfortunately, it's not working properly with an output such as this:

```
Router2#sh ip int brief
Interface               IP Address          Status      Protocol
eth 0/1                192.168.1.1            UP          UP         
eth 0/2                77.77.77.77       UP          UP         
fr 1.501               55.55.55.55       UP          UP         
fr 1.502               66.66.66.66       UP          UP
```

This results in $wan coming back as nothing, when I'm expecting 'fr 1'.

I've worked with a few different regex tools and the expression seems to pass. It's just when I drop it in code that it doesn't. What am I missing?

PS - I'm a network engineer, not a professional coder by trade, so be easy on me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're getting `GigabitEthernet0/0`? Because the regex is wrong and should be:

```
regexp -line -- ^(.*?)(?=(?:\\..*?)?\\s{2,}$rtrname) $expect_out(buffer) wan
                            ^       ^
```

The `-line` flag is to make `^` matches the beginning of a line instead of the whole string.

Since you're not wrapping your expression within braces, you have to double escape the backslashes.

And the regex works for me on the other output as well.

Comment: Jerry, thanks for looking at this. I do seem to be catching a carriage return before the GigabitEthernet0/0; I'll try what you suggest and see if it resolves my issue.

Comment: Okay :) Oh and 1 more thing, you can drop the parentheses around the `.*?` as well, since you're not accessing the captured part at all.

Comment: You got it! It's working now. It's grabbing spaces before the fr 1 (which didn't seem to make it into my examples above), but the router doesn't care, and thus, neither do I :)